# Is reading/writing object from in-proc session an atomic operation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm reading/writing object from session in different threads in single request like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public int Index()
    {
        Task.WaitAll(DoStuff(), DoMoreStuff());
        var foo = Session["foo"] as Foo;
        return foo.MyProperty;
    }

    public Task DoStuff()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var foo = Session["foo"] as Foo;
            if (foo == null || foo.MyProperty == 1)
                foo = new Foo { MyProperty = 1 };
            Session["foo"] = foo;
        });
    }

    public Task DoMoreStuff()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var foo = Session["foo"] as Foo;
            if (foo == null || foo.MyProperty == 1)
                foo = new Foo { MyProperty = 2 };
            Session["foo"] = foo;
        });
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now the logic in this code obviously doesn't make sense but I'm providing it to show what sort of operations I'm doing:

- reading object reference,
- writing object reference,
- creating new object,
- reading object field.

I'm not modifying existing object. Can this code corrupt session state or memory in general?

This is ASP.NET MVC application with default in-proc session implementation.

If this code can corrupt session state should I lock on `Session.SyncRoot` every time I access session in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading and writing references is atomic, but that is moot in this case, as the `HttpSessionState` class is not thread safe.

If one thread sets an item in the session state, and another thread gets or sets an item at the same time, the `HttpSessionState` instance can be corrupted. This would make it behave erratically or cause a crash.

So, yes, if you want to do anything with the session state from different threads, all accesses needs to be in code blocks that are locked using the `SyncRoot` property (or an object of your own if you prefer that).

---

The documentation for the [`HttpSessionState` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) contains this standard declaration:

> "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe."

This means that the static members are thread safe as they don't do anything to specifically break thread safety, and the instance members doesn't do anything to ensure thread safety. It's simply not designed to be thread safe.